# Hello I tried to unite several functions In one single button

Tags: android, unit-testing

I tried a code download manager that goes by pressing the button corresponding download .apk file. The problem is that now I have tried to introduce this function in my application download manager. Activating through a button that already has a function of adding a second function, namely the download manager. Unfortunately not act, no download v1.apk.and I do not understand what we did wrong and adding onclick everything exactly as before.

```
    import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;


import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.widget.Button;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.*;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;
import android.webkit.CookieManager;
import android.webkit.CookieSyncManager;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;


import android.app.AlertDialog;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URL;

import android.os.Environment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.DownloadManager;
import android.app.DownloadManager.Query;
import android.app.DownloadManager.Request;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.io.File;


public class Termeni extends ActionBarActivity {


    private InterstitialAd interstitial;
    private long enqueue;
    private DownloadManager dm;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_termeni);



        AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
        alertDialog.setTitle("Important");
        alertDialog.setMessage("Nu uita sa apesi pe Bannerele publicitare. Fiind o aplicatie gratis singurele benefici sunt cand un utilizator apasa un banner.");
        alertDialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
// here you can add functions
            }
        });
        alertDialog.show();



        accepttermenibuton();
        refuztermenibuton();



        BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                String action = intent.getAction();
                if (DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE.equals(action)) {
                    long downloadId = intent.getLongExtra(
                            DownloadManager.EXTRA_DOWNLOAD_ID, 0);

                    Query query = new Query();
                    query.setFilterById(enqueue);
                    Cursor c = dm.query(query);
                    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                        int columnIndex = c
                                .getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_STATUS);
                        if (DownloadManager.STATUS_SUCCESSFUL == c
                                .getInt(columnIndex)) {


                        }
                    }
                }
            }
    };


        registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter(
                DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE));

    }

    private void accepttermenibuton() {
        Button accionentrar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bAccept);
        accionentrar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(Termeni.this, Categori.class));

            }
        });
    }



    private void refuztermenibuton() {
        Button accionentrar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bRefuz);
        accionentrar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                finish();
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
    }

    public void download_update(View view) {
        dm = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
        Request request = new Request(
                Uri.parse("http://android.vrt.ro/tv-update/v1.apk"));


        String updatePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "Updates" + File.separator + "v1.apk";
        request.setDestinationUri(Uri.fromFile(new File(updatePath)));
        request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir("/updates", "v1.apk");


        enqueue = dm.enqueue(request);
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Verific daca sunt actualizari!" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();


    }

    public void install_update(View view) {
        Intent i = new Intent();
        i.setAction(DownloadManager.ACTION_VIEW_DOWNLOADS);
        startActivity(i);

        Intent promptInstall = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
                .setDataAndType(Uri.parse("file:///sdcard/updates/v2.apk"),
                        "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
        startActivity(promptInstall);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_termeni, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        if (id == R.id.action_help) {
            startActivity(new Intent(Termeni.this, Upgrade.class));
        }


        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```

Comment: Your question really isn't clear.  Can you try to restate it in a more precise way?  "DownloadManager doesn't go" isn't enough.

Comment: never operate download manager you press the button. as onclick function is not something strange act. leave only if the button function download manager, works perfectly. When you add other functions not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct version is as follows, going right now. I hope to help someone else.

```
 public void DownloadUpdateClick(View view) {
        dm = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
        Request request = new Request(
                Uri.parse("http://android.vrt.ro/tv-update/v1.apk"));


        String updatePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "Updates" + File.separator + "v1.apk";
        request.setDestinationUri(Uri.fromFile(new File(updatePath)));
        request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir("/updates", "v1.apk");


        enqueue = dm.enqueue(request);
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Verific daca sunt actualizari!" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();


    }
```